# Wordpress - Add case studies then link 3 onto homepage

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am new to wordpress so sorry for the basic question. How do I have a case studies page, but link 3 case studies to display a shortened version onto my homepage.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Scott

Comment: please elaborate your query

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating a [Custom Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) called case studies.  Add the following to your theme's (or child theme) function.php.

```
// Create Custom Post Type
function my_custom_posttype(){
    register_post_type('case studies',
        // Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Case Studies'),
                'singular_name' => __('Case Study')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'case-studies'),
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_posttype' );
```

This will add a new link in the admin to add new case studies, just like posts and pages.  This is a very basic example, check the link above for more information on post types.

Adding them into the homepage will depend on what theme you are using.